# Cyclical constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, cyclic-reference

I'd like to construct some state machines using constexpr in C++, which requires the states and their transitions to be constexpr as well. If the state machine has a cyclical portion (eg. state 1 has a transition to state 2, and state 2 has a transition to state 1), then cyclical constexpr is required. However, code such as the following doesn't compile (MSVC 2017) as constexpr must be initialized at declaration:

```
class a
{
public:
    constexpr a(a const & v) : v(v) {}
    a const & v;
};

constexpr extern a x;
constexpr a y = a(x);
constexpr a x = a(y);
```

Is there a workaround, or a plan to address this in a future revision of the C++ standard?

Edit: Based on erenon's comment, I tried this:

```
class a
{
public:
    constexpr a(a const & v) : v(v) {}
    a const & v;
};

constexpr a x_getter();

constexpr a y_getter() {
    return a(x_getter());
}

constexpr a x_getter() {
    return a(y_getter());
}

constexpr a test = x_getter();
```

but it fails with an interesting warning message: `Warning C4591 'constexpr' call-depth limit of 512 exceeded` and `expression did not evaluate to a constant` errors at the last line.

Comment: `constexpr extern a x;` I don't really get what this supposed to mean. You can try forward declaring functions, which return the appropriate value.

Comment: @erenon A declaration of `x` is necessary to use it in `y`'s initialiser. Either the `extern` keyword or an initialiser is needed, and the idea is to not provide the initialiser until later. There's nothing special there, it just fundamentally doesn't work, nor would it work with forward-declared functions.

Comment: @erenon updated the question

Comment: @Brent: you have an infinite mutual recursion there. x_getter -> y_getter -> x_getter. Please provide a more meaningful example.

Comment: Even the first example is mutually recursive. That's the whole point of the post.

Comment: Obviously, it does not make sense to have unlimited recursivity at compile-time. Also in a typical state machine, the are multiple possible paths,,,

Comment: Neither would it make sense at runtime. It wouldn't work without `constexpr` so why should it work with it?

Comment: One could get around the recursiveness of the definition with `constexpr std::array<a, 2> arr{arr[1], arr[0]};` but it doesn't compile and would possibly be UB/ill-formed if it did due to referencing objects that have not been created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide `x` and `y` inside a class (or struct). Even if you did not want to have recursive references, this would be beneficial for reasons of information encapsulation:

```
#include <iostream>

class a
{
public:
    // use `a const *` to avoid overriding default copy-constructor
    constexpr a(a const *v_) : v(*v_) {}
    a const & v;
};

struct state_machine
{
    a const x,y;
    constexpr state_machine() : x(&y), y(&x) {}
private:
    // can't copy or move a state_machine (this implicitly deletes operator=):
    state_machine(state_machine&&) = delete;
};

constexpr state_machine sm;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "&x: " << &sm.x << ", &x.v: " << &sm.x.v << '\n';
    std::cout << "&y: " << &sm.y << ", &y.v: " << &sm.y.v << '\n';
    // state_machine sm2{sm}; // forbidden
}
```

Above code was tested with g++ versions 5.4.1 and 6.2.0 using `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14`. I don't have MSVC to check that.

Comment: Don't know why you haven't earned 20 upvotes now; I find your solution really smart.